Microsoft.Web.SessionStateProvider - Timeout Performing EVAL
Can someone help me identify what is the bottleneck here in my Redis Master-Replica setup? Adding some of my observations

This is happening randomly
This suggest that a timeout has occurred while reading the value
Was Redis busy
Was the specified key missing?
Or was the db or the key locked for updation?

PS- I will keep on adding my observations in this post to help others.

Notes:
As per https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts

There are 2 thread pools now:
a) Global (WorkerThreads)
b) Dedicated for async reads (IOCP)
Busy Threads (in both the pools) should be lesser than the Min threads, otherwise new thread injection would be throttled by 500ms, resulting in timeouts.
We must start finetuning the Min threads to be aroung 50 per CPU-Core
We must use async apis of Redis whereever possible
New question: Min threads of the Redis server has to be increased, right?

Updates (27-08-2024):

Min threads of the Redis Client has to be increased
The issue is not of Redis Server, but of Redis Clients
By default the Min Threads of IOCP & Worker is equivalent to the number of CPU cores in the machine running the Redis Client
If the server is free, still the client got a burst of requests(Tasks) to process, spawning of new threads(with the deliberate delay from the OS) will incur a Timeout as the ThreadPool wasn't prepared to handle those many requests.
Use the machine.config file and update <processModel autoConfig="false" minIoThreads="100" minWorkerThreads="100"/> as quoted from the original StackExchange.Redis.Timeouts link below.

Note: I have changed this setting in my PROD, and still observing

How to configure this setting:
In ASP.NET, use the “minIoThreads” configuration setting under the
 configuration element in machine.config. According to
Microsoft, you can’t change this value per site by editing your
web.config (even when you could do it in the past), so the value that
you choose here is the value that all your .NET sites will use. Please
note that you don’t need to add every property if you put autoConfig
in false, just putting autoConfig=”false” and overriding the value is
enough: 
Important Note: the value specified in this configuration element is a
per-core setting. For example, if you have a 4 core machine and want
your minIOThreads setting to be 200 at runtime, you would use
<processModel minIoThreads="50"/>.
Outside of ASP.NET, use one of the methods described in Run-time
configuration options for threading : ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(…) The
ThreadPoolMinThreads MSBuild property The
System.Threading.ThreadPool.MinThreads setting in your
runtimeconfig.json

Edit 09-Sept-2024
Got this error inspite of having min threads 200 in the pool.

Timeout performing EVAL (5000ms), next: EVAL, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0,
aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 911,
last-in: 0, cur-in: 0, sync-ops: 599, async-ops: 0, serverEndpoint:
master.opkeyone-preprod.q1pedd.aps1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379,
conn-sec: 1504.86, aoc: 0, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available,
clientName:
APP4(SE.Redis-v2.7.17.27058)(Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider-v5.1.0.0),
IOCP: (Busy=6,Free=194,Min=200,Max=200), WORKER:
(Busy=9,Free=191,Min=200,Max=200), v: 2.7.17.27058

